# How to extract single string from file line

Tags: c#, substring

I know this is probably a newbie question but I need help with my first C# program.
I need to extract some strings from a file. Every line looks like this:

```
630    FWTRGS782BT a-p     66.12.111.198
```

and need to only retrieve (it is a serial number):

```
FWTRGS782BT
```

I was thinking the correct way could to use line.Substring() but I really don't know how to retrieve it.

Actually every serial number starts by FG or FW, so it could may be possible to extract whenever I get a match with those first two letters and get up till the end of the string (or /t)?

Comment: Does your serial number has a specific length or is it variable?

Comment: You mentioned "or /t" do you mean tab? Are the different parts seperated by tab? In your example it is seperated by whitespaces. Tab would make things easier since you could do `test.Split('\t')[1]` as demonstrated here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fdMIHr

Comment: `test.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]`

Comment: I'd recommend using some sort of CsvHelper lib that you configure to use the appropriate separator. If that's "over the top" for you, I'd expect a serial number to follow one (or a specific, small set of) format(s). In the example I'd guess it has always a specific length, starting index and your "FW|FG". So you could just use substring and then validate for a sanity check.

Comment: ^^ Scrap that. OP commented down below: _"unfortunately, I also have other lines where the "Serial Number element" won't always be the 2nd element of the Array"_.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the leading "630" would allow for telling the exact format of the line? ( And different numbers => different but known formats? )

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string line = "630    FWTRGS782BT a-p     66.12.111.198";

            var lineArr = line.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var requiredText = lineArr.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && x.StartsWith("FW") || x.StartsWith("FG"));
```

Comment: line.Arr.Where() is giving me "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Add using System.Linq; namespace

Comment: @FyXs_Xeno - You would need to add `System.Linq` namespace. See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/t4XdRx

Comment: @FyXs_Xeno Accept the solution if it is working for you so that it can help others.

Answer (score 2):

Here an example of how to read all serial numbers from a file

```
    private List<string> GetAllSerialNumbersFromDocument(string pathToFile) //something like "C://folder/folder/file.txt"
    {
        List<string> serialNumbers = new List<string>(); //list where all serial numbers are stored

        using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new StreamReader(pathToFile)) //Use 'using' because TextReader implements IDisposable
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) //read all lines
            {
                serialNumbers.Add(GetSerialNumber(line)); //Get serial number of line and save it into list
            }               
        }

        return serialNumbers; //return all serial numbers
    }
    private string GetSerialNumber(string line)
    {
        var singleElements = line.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //split elements
        return singleElements.First(x => x.StartsWith("FW") || x.StartsWith("FG")); //Get serial number
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var input = "630    FWTRGS782BT a-p     66.12.111.198";
  var output = input.Split( new char []{ ' ' }, 
               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);                                       
  Console.WriteLine(output[1]);  //➙ FWTRGS782BT
```

Comment: user is expecting serial number till end of text and it should start with either FG or FW.

Comment: @AmitVerma That was only a proposition that OP came up with. It's brittle _at best_ and "till EOT" is definitely not going to work.

Comment: Yes that could have been correct but unfortunately, I also have other lines where the "Serial Number element" won't always be the 2nd element of the Array:

Comment: @FyXs_Xeno ^^ That would be **important** info to add to the question!